# Please help with finding an output for this function $f(x)=2|x-1|+|x+1|$ after injecting an interval $A=(0,2]$ to this function

Tags: functions

Please help with finding an output for this function $f(x)=2|x-1|+|x+1|$ after injecting an interval $A=]0,2]$ to this function. The domain of this function is natural.

To solve this, I would normally make X to be defined by an expression with Y in it ,but I do not know how to do that here because there is an absolute value of X only.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

1. Look at the values $f_{(-\infty,-1]}, f_{[-1,1]}, f_{[1, \infty)}$ of $f$ on each of the intervals $(-\infty,-1], [-1,1], [1, \infty)$ as those are the ones where you can get rid of the absolute values.
2. On each of those intervals $f$ is linear, nice functions!
3. Compute $A_1=f[(0,1]]$ and $A_2=f([1,2]]$
4. Finally use the fact that $f[A]= A_1 \cup A_2$ to get the result you're looking for.

**Good luck!**

Answer (score 1):

Redefine the function into a piece wise function. Break the definition when any one of the modulus function vanishes. Here the second one is always positive, so you don't need to do anything about it. The first one vanishes at $x=1$. Now, for $0\lt x\leq 1$, 
$$f(x)= 2(1-x) + x+1= 3-x$$
While, for $1\lt x \leq 2$,
$$f(x)= 2(x-1) + x+1=3x-1$$
Now can you proceed?

Comment: Yes, thank you!